# Cisco - what is the purpose of a gigabit ethernet switching module

Tags: networking, cisco-catalyst, switch

Cisco noob here

Recetly while looking for a cisco switch and router combination for my CCNA studies i won this bid for a (I added the bid to keep track of it and i ended up winning it)

```
Cisco-4500-Series-WS-X4424-GB-RJ45-Gigabit-Ethernet-Switching module
```

Bid ended very cheap, i looked around and i cant find any info regarding the purpose of these switching modules. from the pictures it doesn't have a console port:

[image: module pic]

Comment: You've purchased a switch module but you have no switch to install the module in. If you're looking for a study kit, take a look at this link. You'll get lifetime support, tested good equipment and additional study materials and tools. I've purchased kits from here before - http://www.certificationkits.com/ccna-certification-kits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Higher end networking equipment tends to be modular, and come with a chassis with a set of module slots. Typically the main board will take up a slot (or possibly 2 in a redundant configuration) and the rest are available to mix and match high density or higher speed copper and fibre modules.

It's no use to anyone without the chassis and management card, and people are dumping them because they are end of life - buyer's market.